# Google maps doesn't work ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, google

I have Ubuntu 18.04 with Windows 10 installed and Google maps worked fine for a while but for a week or so it has stopped working. I can't open the map window at all.

Comment: What do you mean by "Ubuntu 18.04 with Windows 10 installed" and "Google maps stopped working"?

Comment: Dual OS, Google maps doesn't open at all. For example, I put a city in google search and then choose ''Maps'' and all I get is a blank window. It works when I use Firefox though...

Comment: So it works in Firefox. Where it doesn't work?

Comment: Forgot to say, doesn't work wiyh Chrome

Comment: It works for me. Did you try to tune something using `chrome://flags`? Anyway Chrome problems are off-topic.